# What is Push Button Scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just read a term Push Button Scaling in AWS. I realy didn't get what does it mean exactly in terms of scalebility. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a very fancy term to say you can scale your instance resources using a graphical user interface. To be precise, it means that you can scale the size of an instance(memory, CPU, PIOPS, disk etc) either up or down, with the click of a button.

Comment: @AliHussainKhan Your'e welcome and you can mark the answer as well if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Push-button scalability : This means that you can scale the database without incurring any downtime. It may be used when using in-memory database service like Amazon ElastiCache service of AWS.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?